# Print the binary format of a char

Tags: c++, c

I wrote a function to print the binary format of a `char` months ago, it was like this and it worked well:

```
void PrnCharBit(char x)
{
        int i,mask;
        for(i=CHAR_BIT;i>=1;i--)
        {
            mask=(1<<(i-1))&x;
            putchar((mask==0)?'0':'1');
        }
        putchar('\n');
}
```

And today I want to use this function so I wrote one almost the same as the function above:

```
void PrnCharBit(char c)
{
    int i;
    char mask=0;
    //printf("%d\n",CHAR_MAX);
    for(i=sizeof(char)*CHAR_BIT-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        mask=1<<i;
        if(mask&c==0) putchar('0');
        else putchar('1');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

However, the second function didn't work. I can't figure out why, because the two functions are almost the same! Why does the second function not produce the same result?

Comment: Why don't you just use the first function?  It works and is shorter.

Comment: What is the value of CHAR_BIT ?. if the PrnCharBit('#'); then what is the binary value should be ?

Comment: Since this is tagged C++, `std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT>(c);`

Comment: Operator precedence. Clang warns as follows `& has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first` - in your second function change `if(mask&c==0)` to `if((mask&c)==0)`.

Comment: Please note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by the standard (regardless of the underlying platform).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Operator [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The equality operator (`==`) is ordered before the bitwise operation (`&`).

Clang warns as follows;

> & has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first

In your second function change `if(mask&c==0)` to `if((mask&c)==0)`

Comment: thx! the bug is fixed!(It is so strange that the & IS lower than ==)